Slope equation in graph plot
I'm trying to get the equation of the plotted graph to show up on it, but it keeps showing me an equation equal to zero, which it clearly isn't. When I run my code, the graph is fine, perfect really, but I know the equation shouldn't be giving anything like this.
Here is the code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Section 1: Calculating values of H for toroid A

# defining the values to find H for toroid A
N_1 = 3420
L_1 = 0.076
R_1 = 8

# defining function to find the value of H with given V_1
def H_toroid_A(V_1):
    return (V_1 * N_1) / (L_1 * R_1)

# Section 2: Calculating the delta list of uncertainties for H toroid A

# defining variables and uncertainties
V_1_values = [0.198, 0.266, 0.340, 0.402, 0.505]
delta_V_1_values = [0.050, 0.050, 0.050, 0.050, 0.1]  # uncertainties for V_1
delta_N_1 = 0  # uncertainty for N_1
delta_L_1 = 0.001  # uncertainty for L_1
delta_R_1 = 0.4  # uncertainty for R_1

# function to calculate uncertainties in H
def calculate_uncertainty_H(V_values, delta_V_values, delta_N, delta_L, delta_R):
    uncertainties = []
    for i in range(len(V_values)):
        uncertainty_H = np.sqrt(
            ((V_values[i] / (L_1 * R_1)) * delta_N)**2 +
            ((N_1 / (L_1 * R_1)) * delta_V_values[i])**2 +
            ((-V_values[i] * N_1 / (L_1**2 * R_1)) * delta_L)**2 +
            ((-V_values[i] * N_1 / (L_1 * R_1**2)) * delta_R)**2
        )
        uncertainties.append(uncertainty_H)
    return uncertainties

uncertainties_H = calculate_uncertainty_H(V_1_values, delta_V_1_values, delta_N_1, delta_L_1, delta_R_1)

# Section 3: Calculating values of B for toroid A

# defining the values to find B for toroid A
R_2 = 270000
C = 220e-9
N_2 = 820
A_2 = 9.025e-5

# defining function to find the value of B with given V_c
def B_toroid_A(V_c):
    return (R_2 * C * V_c) / (N_2 * A_2)

# Section 4: Calculating list of uncertainties for B toroid A

# defining variables and uncertainties
V_c_values = [0.0266, 0.0372, 0.0505, 0.0605, 0.076]
delta_V_c_values = [0.005, 0.005, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]  # uncertainties for V_c
delta_N_2 = 0  # uncertainty for N_2
delta_C = 1.1e-8  # uncertainty for C
delta_A_2 = 5e-8  # uncertainty for A_2
delta_R_2 = 13500  # uncertainty for R_2

# function to calculate uncertainties in B
def calculate_uncertainty_B(V_values, delta_V_values, delta_N, delta_C, delta_A, delta_R):
    uncertainties = []
    for i in range(len(V_values)):
        uncertainty_B = np.sqrt(
            ((C * V_values[i]) / (N_2 * A_2))**2 * delta_R_2**2 +
            ((R_2 * V_values[i]) / (N_2 * A_2))**2 * delta_C**2 +
            ((R_2 * C) / (N_2 * A_2))**2 * delta_V_values[i]**2 +
            ((R_2 * C * V_values[i]) / (N_2 * A_2**2))**2 * delta_A_2**2 +
            ((R_2 * C * V_values[i]) / (N_2**2 * A_2))**2 * delta_N_2**2
        )
        uncertainties.append(uncertainty_B)
    return uncertainties

uncertainties_B = calculate_uncertainty_B(V_c_values, delta_V_c_values, delta_N_2, delta_C, delta_A_2, delta_R_2)

# Section Alpha: calculating list of values of H
H_values = [H_toroid_A(V_1) for V_1 in V_1_values]

# Section Beta: calculating list of values of B
B_values = [B_toroid_A(V_c) for V_c in V_c_values]

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.errorbar(H_values, B_values, xerr=uncertainties_H, yerr=uncertainties_B, fmt='o', label='Data Points')
plt.xlabel('H (Intensité du champ magnétique)')
plt.ylabel('B (Densité du flux magnétique)')
plt.title('Courbe Hysteresis')

# Performing linear regression with uncertainties
coefficients, cov_matrix = np.polyfit(H_values, B_values, 1, w=1/np.array(uncertainties_B), cov=True)
slope = coefficients[0]
intercept = coefficients[1]

# Plotting the linear fit
plt.plot(H_values, slope * np.array(H_values) + intercept, color='red', label=f'Linear Fit: B = {slope:.2f} * H + {intercept:.2f}')
plt.legend()

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Technically it does show the slope equation but it's wrong. I have no idea why it is equal to zero. Plotted graph

Post a jpg of the graph, so people can help you better.

It seem the values are very close to zero so the format .2f truncate the values. Have you tried with a more precise format like 12.5e ?

Switching out the .2f for a more precise format, that is 12.5e. Suggested by manu190466.
